# Tikz, error in computation of coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I would like to draw 3 vectors starting at (m) and with computed length, but things go wrong.
Basically I get an error or a rendering error (according to the differend attempts) in the 1st and 3rd lines at the end:

```
\draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ($-155:1*sin(65)$) coordinate (m);
\draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ($-65:1*cos(65)$) coordinate (m);
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
  interface/.style={
        postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-45,
                    amplitude=0.15cm,segment length=1mm}}},
  ]
  \draw[black,line width=.5pt,interface](1,0)--(-1,0);
  \draw[dotted, thin] (0,0) -- (0,-2.5);
  \coordinate (m) at (-65:2);
  \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (m);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip(-1,0) rectangle (1,-2.5);
    \draw[thin] (0,0) circle(2);
  \end{scope}
  \node[bullet, minimum size=4pt] at (m) {};
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ($-155:1*sin(65)$) coordinate (m);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- (-90:1) coordinate (m);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ($-65:1*cos(65)$) coordinate (m);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need braces (and no `$` as far as I can see) e.g. `(-155:{1*sin(65)})`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thank you! there is another error: the 3 lines should start at (m) every times, instead (why?) they start at the end of the previous segment

Comment: This is because you overwrite `m` with `coordinate (m)`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat , ok, then I miss completely the meaning. Its a decomposition of the grav. force, all arrow should look downwards, with the angles, -155,-90,-65 all in the 3rd and 4th quadrants, that is downwards

Comment: You mean `\draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-155:{1*sin(65)});
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-90:1);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-65:{1*cos(65)});`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you very much. Now it remain a small trigon. error... for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do computations that involve some parentheses, you need braces. I also do not think you need `$` here since you just use polar coordinates (and do not use coordinate computations a la `calc`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
  interface/.style={
        postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-45,
                    amplitude=0.15cm,segment length=1mm}}},
  ]
  \draw[black,line width=.5pt,interface](1,0)--(-1,0);
  \draw[dotted, thin] (0,0) -- (0,-2.5);
  \coordinate (m) at (-65:2);
  \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (m);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip(-1,0) rectangle (1,-2.5);
    \draw[thin] (0,0) circle(2);
  \end{scope}
  \node[bullet, minimum size=4pt] at (m) {};
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- (-155:{1*sin(65)}) coordinate (m);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- (-90:1) coordinate (m);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- (-65:{1*cos(65)}) coordinate (m);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This code redefines `m`, i.e. if you say

```
\draw[->, very thin] (m) -- (-155:{1*sin(65)}) coordinate (m);
```

then `m` will be the coordinate at `(-155:{1*sin(65)})`, and so on. If you do not want to do that, use e.g. (based on your comments)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
  interface/.style={
        postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-45,
                    amplitude=0.15cm,segment length=1mm}}},
  ]
  \draw[black,line width=.5pt,interface](1,0)--(-1,0);
  \draw[dotted, thin] (0,0) -- (0,-2.5);
  \coordinate (m) at (-65:2);
  \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (m);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip(-1,0) rectangle (1,-2.5);
    \draw[thin] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
  \end{scope}
  \node[bullet, minimum size=4pt] at (m) {};
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-155:{1*sin(65)});
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-90:1);
  \draw[->, very thin] (m) -- ++(-65:{1*cos(65)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]